# UIButtons in Landscape dont show their titles

Tags: objective-c

I have a strange thing and I would like to fi that.
I have a View which is in landscape mode. Due to landscape mode I have a button which need to change his frame:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 40.0, 160.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Normal:

> button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

Landscape:

> button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 40.0, 160.0);

All is fine, except the Title of the Button: "SHow View"

Instead of saying Show view it says this:

```
w

e

i

V

w

o

h

S
```

read this from button to top :P
This is my button title, because its landscape, but the titles go still for Portrait.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Can't you give screen shots ? I think it would be more clear :)

Comment: Strange thing,I guess the button does not recognize that it is landscape mode.. I'll make a screenshot asap

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems you are not setting the rect of your button right. Remember that the third parameter, is the width:

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin.x = x; rect.origin.y = y;
  rect.size.width = width; rect.size.height = height;
  return rect;
}
```

In `button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 40.0, 160.0);` you are setting the width of your button to 40.

More importantly, you should use strings and struts, or even better, auto layout. Life is so much easier when you let computers do the math. For just one button, springs and struts is all you need, but if you want to create a more flexible interface, and you can target iOS 6, then you should use autolayout.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[[self view] addSubview:button];

NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                                        toItem:nil
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                    multiplier:1
                                                                      constant:200];

[button addConstraint:widthConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *bottomContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:[self view]
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:-20];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:[self view]
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0];
NSArray *constraints = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:bottomContraint, centerContraint, nil];
[[self view] addConstraints:constraints];
```

And if you want to use springs and struts, you have to set the autoresizing mask:

```
[button setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)];
```

These two things are much more easier in Interface Builder.